# Routing the client app after an account verification

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am building a webapp using nodeJS as the server-side framework and reactJS as the client-side framework.
My issue is the following:

I'm trying to create an account registration mechanism, which is working fine. I do receive an email with a specifc token in order to active an account. The issue that I am facing is that the API which will consume is on the nodeJS side, and I can't figure out how I can force a page to being rendered from the client side as a result of the success, since the API is located on the server on a different port?

Am I approaching this wrongly, and as such I am facing this specific issue?

Comment: there is no nodejs language

Comment: I am assuming you are using express. If you are, use `res.redirect('yourreactsite.com/path/to/success/page')` as the response to success.

Comment: If you're using React + React Router and you just want to redirect a user to a different page after successful action you can do it like `props.history.push('/path/to/success/page')`  

Whole article here: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/

Answer (score 0):

It's simple you just handle it on both sides,
meaning that you send a verification link in the email so it redirects the user to your application and then on the client app extract the toke (the verification code needed on the verification link from the email) and send it to the server(API) depending on the request status you will take an action, if its verified successfully you will redirect the user to home (or to log in again, or it does not show an error message!